# How can I fill a large container in a shallow sink?

Tags: water, sink, taps

I'm moving into a dormitory building and the bathroom sinks are very shallow. I want to be able to pour water into my Brita water filter but it doesn't fit beneath the tap. I was thinking of getting some surgical tubing and slipping it over the nozzle and putting the other end in the water filter. Can anyone think of a better idea? I also thought of cutting a gardening hose and using it in the same way. Obviously I don't own the building so I can't do anything permanent. This doesn't have to work super well, if some water leaks into the sink that's ok.

Answer (score 9):

You could also get one of these items and use it to transfer water from the sink tap to the Brita water filter/pitcher.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are lots of items you can use to build a path from the faucet to a pitcher outside of the sink. Get creative, or use the popular internet solution, a dust pan:

[image: dust pan sink extender]

Comment: lucky your putting it into a filter... ;-)

Comment: @unecs Presumably you'd use a separate dust pan for the dusting. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Take your Britta pitcher into the shower room and fill it from the showerhead.

Answer (score 5):

you could use a tap-shower adapter and just cut the shower rose off. [One example of a tap-shower adapter](http://www.fixatap.com.au/product/single-push-on-white-spray-hand-piece/219831)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the same idea as a dust pan, you can cut down a 2L Coke bottle to make a long funnel.

Comment: Recently found myself encountering this exact problem as I wanted to fill my water bottles in such a sink, and this was the simplest solution by far for me. I just cut the bottom off one of my bottles, and can easily use that to funnel water directly into the other bottles.